Vertex packing for higher path lengths
I have an undirected, connected graph $G$, and I want to choose $k$ vertices so that I maximize the minimal path length between any pair. Intuitively, imagine that the $k$ vertices repel each other, and I am looking for configurations where the $k$ vertices are evenly spaced in the graph, so no pair is close together.
Here is an inefficient solution to this problem.
Consider the distance matrix $D$ of the graph $G$, where the entries are the minimal path length between any two vertices. From this matrix we can construct graphs $H_m$ whose edges connect vertices whose path length is at most $m$. Then, we can solve the independent set problem on $H_m$ for $m = 1,2,3,...$ until the size of the independent set is less than $k$. This tells us the maximal $m$ for which our $k$ vertices have path distance at least $m$ between any pair.
However, the independent set problem is hard, and solving it many times is surely not optimal.
Is there a fast exact algorithm for this problem? Is there a fast approximate algorithm (perhaps along the "vertexes repelling" line of thought)? Where could I find such algorithms implemented?

After precomputing the distance matrix $D$, you can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let $\bar{D}=\max_{i<j} D_{ij}$.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected. Introduce binary (or just nonnegative) decision variable $y_{ij}$ to represent $x_i \land x_j$. Let $z$ represent the minimal path length $\min_{i<j: y_{ij}} D_{ij}$.  The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= k \tag1\label1 \\
y_{ij} &\ge x_i + x_j - 1 &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag2\label2 \\
z &\le D_{ij} y_{ij} + \bar{D} (1-y_{ij}) &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects exactly $k$ nodes.
Constraints \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} enforce the logical implication $(x_i \land x_j) \implies z \le D_{ij}$.
Imposing the following optional valid constraints will likely reduce the solve time:
$$\sum_{j:i<j} y_{ij} + \sum_{j:i>j} y_{ji} = (k-1)x_i \quad \text{for all $i$} \tag4\label4$$
The idea of \eqref{4} is that node $i$ has $k-1$ selected neighbors if $x_i=1$ and no selected neighbors if $x_i=0$.
See also https://blogs.sas.com/content/subconsciousmusings/2021/03/18/automated-linearization-in-sas-optimization/

I am not too versed with ILP, can you let me know what would be the worst case time complexity here? I have a hypothesis that what OP suggested, is actually the lower bound on the problem and you will have to solve for independent set at least once ( or worse)

@EnEm ILP is typically NP-hard but can perform well in practice.  If you stop early, you get lower and upper bounds on the optimal objective value.

Thanks! It’s really neat to see how you linearize the product $x_i x_j$ by introducing the $y$ variables. I’ll try implementing this and see how it does.

Glad to help.  How big are $G$ and $k$?
